# HList transformation Out type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have created a wrapper on top on `HList` that can append an `HLists`. It is defined as follows:

```
class HListWrapper[L <: HList](val hl: L) {
  def append[V, Out <: HList](k: Witness, v: V)(implicit updater: Updater.Aux[L, FieldType[k.T, V], Out],
                                                lk: LacksKey[L, k.T]): HListWrapper[Out] = {
    new HListWrapper(updater(hl, field[k.T](v)))
  }
}
object HListWrapper {
  def apply[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L]) =
    new HListWrapper(gen.to(p))
}
```

It used like this:

```
case class CC(i: Int, ii: Int)
val cc = CC(100, 1000)
val hl = HListWrapper(cc)
hl.append('iii, 10000)
```

But when I try to put the `HListWrapper` inside another function to capture the type of `Out`, the compiler cannot seem to resolve the final type of the transformation (fails with type mismatch error):

```
def cctohlist[Out <: HList]: CC => HListWrapper[Out] = {
  m => {
    val hl = HListWrapper(m)
    hl.append('iii, 10000)
  }
}
```

The primary reason to create the `cctohlist` method is to get the type of the `HList` after append. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works:

```
def cctohlist: CC => HListWrapper[Record.`'i -> Int, 'ii -> Int, 'iii -> Int`.T] = {
    m => {
      val hl = HListWrapper(m)
      hl.append('iii, 10000)
    }
  }
```

When you write

```
def cctohlist[Out <: HList]: CC => HListWrapper[Out] = ???
```

this means I can apply `cctohlist[Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil]` and have `CC => HListWrapper[Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil]` or I can apply `cctohlist[AnyVal :: AnyRef :: Any :: HNil]` and have `CC => HListWrapper[AnyVal :: AnyRef :: Any :: HNil]` etc. This is obviously not the case.

---

This is generic one:

```
def cctohlist[P <: Product, L <: HList, Out <: HList](m: P)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
  updater: Updater.Aux[L, FieldType[Witness.`'iii`.T, Int], Out],
  lk: LacksKey[L, Witness.`'iii`.T]
  ): HListWrapper[Out] = {
    val hl = HListWrapper(m)
    hl.append('iii, 10000)
  }

cctohlist(cc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated. Is there any other way to refactor `cctolist` to obtain the type of the `HList` after append?